# Can I log variable value to a file without break points in gdb?

Tags: c, gdb, breakpoints

Is it possible to log for ex: array values to a log file without using break points in gdb?

I used this:

```
set logging on some_file
b func
command 1
p print_clock_cycles    
c
end
```

Aim: To log the clock cycles value to a file through gdb. The logging can be infinite so I cannot use the existing memory.

My problem: In case I am printing the clock cycles by reading a register, the value is different when printed with the above script when compared to without breakpoint (reading by some other means which I do not want to use due to memory constraints). I am assuming gdb is taking some more time to print when we have a break point which is affecting the clock cycles. I do not have any other debugger for ex jtag attached.

Is there any other means by which I can log the value?

Thanks

Comment: What OS are you on? What language are you using? (C, C++, Objective-C, something else?) What have you tried for writing to a file?

Comment: Using C (Tagged) and RTOS. Writing 32bit values to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a serial port available?  When I develop on embedded platforms, that's a good way to save debugging information.

I wrote functions to manage the serial port.  My "print" functions queue up string data in a buffer, and the serial ISR drains data out of the buffer.  As long as the serial port can drain the buffer fast enough it never fills up.